# What happens when .NET Core hosting bundle's version is behind development machine versions

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

### Situation

Today there is a security vulnerability in .NET Core 2.1 and we have all of our developers update their .NET Core 2.1.x to .NET Core 2.1.10 but no idea when we'll get around to updating the .NET Core hosting bundles on our production web servers.

### Questions

1. Does the fact that we updated our developer machines become nullified because we haven't updated the web servers yet?
2. Once our developer's code is pushed to production will those apps run against the older libraries for .NET Core that are on our web servers or will they somehow run in the newer version that our developer machines are building with?
3. If our projects once pushed to production run under an older version of .NET Core libraries, will we run into compatiblity issues because our developers built against an older version?
4. I guess my ultimate question is, should we always have a policy in our company to update the hosting bundles on our web servers before we update our development machines?

Comment: It is too broad to discuss, as different issues require different resolutions, https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues Sometimes you only need to upgrade the runtime, while in other cases you need to update hosting bundles, but the actual announcements contain the instructions. If you do want a company policy, follow Microsoft's articles please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you wanna benefit from the update done from .NET Core 2.1.x to .NET Core 2.1.10, I would say : while you don't update the servers, yes.
2. The apps will try to run under the installed framework on the ervers. If you are publishing using the default mode, your code will depend on the framework installed on your production machines. However, you can change to **self contained deployment** mode and embed the framework with your code to work on "targeted platform" (https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/496/net-core-self-contained-and-framework-dependent-deployments-explained).
3. It should remain compatible because the versions are both 2.1.x. However I would not try it in production before having tested it in a separated environment.
4. I believe you should not update your production servers before having tested the new version first. I would change the targeted framework on my development machine, then I would update the framework and the code in (at least) a pre-prod environment. I would test it in this environment. And only then, I would consider a change on the production servers.

**Point 3. EDITED based on Daboul comment**

Comment: I was about to send a very similar answer for 1, 2 and 4. For 3, I would say that if the runtime on the server is a 2.1.X then even if the dev machine is a little bit more recent, if it remains a 2.1.X it should be compatible. Same major and minor integer should mean compatibility here, no?

Comment: @Daboul Your are right, it should work. However I would not try to verify it in production. I will update my answer to be more precise.